# I can't access my wp-admin dashboard

Tags: login

I have reset my password more than once now to ensure I have the right username and password.

I try login to my wp-admin for my site.

It requests username and password. It then goes to this page:

[image: Jetpack login page]

I click login.

It takes me back to this:

[image: Site login]

This is with the correct username and password, double-checked.

Please advise on what might be going on.

Comment: Is your site hosted with wordpress.com? Have you tried reaching out to their support?

Comment: Welcome to wpse! If you have access to the file manager/ftp you can disable the plugin by renaming its folder